# Python 3: Using subprocess to take photo via gphoto2 but can't set custom filename doing it.

Tags: python, subprocess, libgphoto2

everything works fine while I do it via  terminal but when I use python script it doesn't.

Command:
`gphoto2 --capture-image-and-download --filename test2.jpg`

```
New file is in location /capt0000.jpg on the camera                            
Saving file as test2.jpg
Deleting file /capt0000.jpg on the camera
```

I'ts all good.
But when I try to do it via python script and subprocess nothing happens. I tried to do it like:

```
import subprocess
text1 = '--capture-image-and-download"' 
text2 = '--filename "test2.jpg"'
print(text1 +" "+ text2)
test = subprocess.Popen(["gphoto2", text1, text2], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = test.communicate()[0]
print(output)
```

and:

```
import subprocess
test = subprocess.Popen(["gphoto2", "--capture-image-and-download --filename'test2.jpg'"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = test.communicate()[0]
print(output)
```

While I use only  `--capture-image-and-download` it works fine, but I get filename that I don't want to. Can you tell me what I do wrong?!

Comment: Have you tried : `test = subprocess.Popen(["gphoto2", text1, text2], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)` ?

Comment: For the second try, you have to put a comma between `--capture-image-and-download` and `--filename'test2.jpg'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the command line, quotes and spaces are consumed by the shell; with `shell=False` you need to split up the tokens on whitespace yourself (and ideally understand how the shell processes quotes; or use [`shlex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html) to do the work for you).

```
import subprocess

test = subprocess.Popen([
        "gphoto2",
        "--capture-image-and-download",
        "--filename", "test2.jpg"],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = test.communicate()[0]
print(output)
```

Unless you are stuck on a truly paleolithic Python version, you should avoid `supbrocess.Popen()` in favor of `subprocess.run()` (or, for slightly older Python versions, `subprocess.check_output()`). The lower-level `Popen()` interface is unwieldy, but gives you low-level access control for when the higher-level API doesn't do what you want.

Comment: Sadly doesn't work. `b'For debugging messages, please use the --debug option.\nDebugging messages may help finding a solution to your problem.\nIf you intend to send any error or debug messages to the gphoto\ndeveloper mailing list <gphoto-devel@lists.sourceforge.net>, please run\ngphoto2 as follows:\n\n    env LANG=C gphoto2 --debug --debug-logfile=my-logfile.txt --capture-image-and-download --filename "test2.jpg"\n\nPlease make sure there is sufficient quoting around the arguments.\n\n'`

Comment: I don't have `gphoto2` so I can't really say wtat's wrong. Maybe do pass in `--debug` and maybe add `env=myenv` to the `subprocess` call where you override `LANG` (`import os; myenv = os.environ.copy(); myenv["LANG"] = "C"`)